# Connect to a device with Wifi, yet continue to the the cellular connection for internet data?

Tags: android, wifi, cellular-network

Can someone tell me is there a way to connect to a device with Wifi, yet continue to the cellular connection for internet data? Basically, I need to connect my phone to drone Wifi but I want to be able to use the cellular connection for internet access, for example, to share photos I have taken from the drone.

Answer (score 0):

I see it says **Android** but what version of **Android** and what model is the phone (Samsung, LG, etc) you are trying to connect with? Also, what drone model is it that you are flying?

If you are using Samsung I would suggest trying the data boost option that allows you to use both wifi and mobile data, they advertise it as a faster way to download things but I have a feeling this will help in your case as well, if not I be interested in your results.

Comment: I want to make this possible on every Android device that uses Android above 4.3.  So I was thinking if there is a way to make this programmatically.

Comment: Well what exactly happens when you connect? I mean my experience when connecting an android to a gopro wifi still allows me to share and download. But more detail on what happens on your end may help others understand and help.

Comment: For now, I have an application that connects the device with the drone wifi and uses the drone camera for taking photos and videos but I don't have an internet access to share the photos directly from the application. What I want to accomplish is while I am connected to the drone Wifi to be also connected to 3g and use the cellular data to share the photos directly from the application.